# Prevent menu-bar from expanding too much

Tags: frames, menu-bar

The way I have things configured, some Emacs modes end up adding a lot of entries to the menu-bar. As a result, the Emacs frame increases in width. This results in various annoyances.

For now, I've disabled `menu-bar-mode` and use `menu-bar-open` as needed, but is there any way to get Emacs to display something like an "overflow" button in the  menu-bar, which I can click to access the entries that don't fit in the default width?

Comment: Good question. Library [`tool-bar+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToolBar#ToolBarPlus) does just that for the tool-bar. Doing it for the menu-bar would be useful. Another approach could be to just combine existing standard menus in a single menu (with branches).